# Not quite sure how to write the formula mathematically

Tags: excel, vba

So I am a student currently studying VBA. I'm doing ok in the class but still kind of iffy on what how to program. For the question I'm on I have to take numbers in a column and multiply them unless they are less than or equal to zero. Here is an example done by hand of what the result should look like (which are not the same numbers as the actual problem, these are much simpler).

Here is what I have written so far. I'm kinda treating the column as a 1 x 10 array.

```
Function multpos(C As Variant)
Dim i As Integer
Dim MD As Long
    For i = 1 To 9
        MD = C(1, i) * C(1, i + 1)
    Next i
If C(i, 1) > 0 Then C(i, 1) = C(i, 1) Else C(i, 1) = 1
If C(i + 1, 1) > 0 Then C(i + 1, 1) = C(i + 1, 1) Else C(i + 1, 1) = 1
multpos = MD
End Function
```

While MD satisfies the equation, it only works for the first two and then doesn't. Intuitively I want to do something like this

```
     MD = C(1, i) * C(1, i)
Next i
```

Etc but this is also not mathematically correct. So if I had

```
MD = C(1, i)
```

how can I get it to multiply by the next value from here? Feel free to look at my other code and correct me as well since that could just as easily be wrong. Thank you for help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work for you.  I tried to comment the code for clarity:

```
Public Function PRODUCTIF(ByVal vValues As Variant, ByVal sCriteria As String) As Double

    Dim vVal As Variant
    Dim dResult As Double

    'Iterate through vValues and evaluate against the criteria for numeric values only
    For Each vVal In vValues
        If IsNumeric(vVal) Then
            If Evaluate(vVal & sCriteria) = True Then
                'Value is numeric and passed the criteria, multiply it with our other values
                'Note that until a valid value is found, dResult will be 0, so simply set it equal to the first value to avoid a 0 result
                If dResult = 0 Then dResult = vVal Else dResult = dResult * vVal
            End If
        End If
    Next vVal

    'Output result
    PRODUCTIF = dResult

End Function
```

And you would call the function like this: `=PRODUCTIF(A1:A10,">0")`

Comment: Worked very well and I like it better than using the for values as you can make the column as large as you want. I still will need learn how to do it with loops but I will ask my professor about that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you could exploit `AutoFiler()` method

```
Function multpos(C As Range, criteria As String)
    Dim MD As Long
    Dim cell As Range

    With C.Columns(1)
        If IsEmpty(.Cells(1, 1)) Then .Cells(1, 1) = "|header|"
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=criteria
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then
            MD = 1
            For Each cell In C.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
                MD = MD * cell.Value
            Next cell
        End If
        If .Cells(1, 1) = "|header|" Then .Cells(1, 1).ClearContents
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
    multpos = MD
End Function
```

to be exploited in your main sub like:

```
MsgBox multpos(Range("A1:A10"), ">0")
```